# A non trivial example of a Gaussian semi-Markov process?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-process

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal A, \mathbb P)$ be a probability space and $X=(X_t)$ a real Gaussian stochastic process.

Let $\mathcal F=(\mathcal F_t)$ be the filtration generated by $(X_t)$.

$X$ is Markov with regard to $\mathcal F$ iff $\mathbb P [X_t \in \cdot | \mathcal F_s ] = \mathbb P [X_t \in \cdot | X_s ]$ for $s<t$.

$X$ is semi-Markov with regard to $\mathcal F$ iff there exists an $n>0$ such that  $\mathbb P [X_t \in \cdot | \mathcal F_s ] = \mathbb P [X_t \in \cdot | X_{u_1}, \cdots, X_{u_n}, X_s ]$ for $s<t$ and any $u_1<\ldots < u_n<s$. Here I excluded Markov processes from the class of semi-Markov processes.

Brownian motion is an example of Markov process. What is a canonical example of a Gaussian semi-Markov process ?

Comment: I cannot talk about a *canonical* example, but I believe that (non-independent) random time changes of a Wiener process lead to processes which are semi-Markov but not Markov. This may be a general way to produce such processes. I will look for a reference of such a statement, but this could be what you want, in the sense that it is the most canonically simple construction of a semi-Markov non-Markov process.

Comment: If you have a specific example that satisfies the above property the bounty is yours!

Comment: Update : Struggling to prove Gaussian nature of the process, everything else is done. I will try to get some work done on this one.

Comment: I struggled and haggled , but cannot reward you with an answer. I am just left with the thought that a lot of integrals against the BM, take say $\int_0^t B_s dB_s$ are non-Markovian and are Gaussian, and I'd like to think that many of them are semi-Markov. I struggled to prove this.

Comment: Do you have something not Gaussian and still semi-Markov ?

Comment: Oh, you mean a semi-markov process which is not Markov and not Gaussian? Well, you can have a continuous time random walk, where the inter-jump times aren't iid exponential (as they are in the Markovian case) but some other distribution.

Comment: Sorry, I meant continuous, semi-Markov, not Markov, not necessarily Gaussian

Comment: There's a whole book on continuous semi-Markov process, but all it does is go over the definition of semi-Markov kernels and so on. I did not see a single example there, apart from the fact that it says "random time changes of a BM can be semi-Markov". The book is titled "continuous semi-Markov processes" by Boris Harlamov. You can take a look.

Comment: You can also see [this](https://www.kellogg.northwestern.edu/research/math/papers/118.pdf) paper. I tried my best, but I thank you for showing me a new part of probability, which I really enjoyed seeing. +1